# boost lockfree queue behavior in case fixed_sized<true>

Tags: c++, boost, queue, lock-free

when i declare my queue as

```
typedef boost::lockfree::queue<MyMessage, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true>> MessageQueue
```

and i try to use the queue as a multiple-producer-single-consumer queue, i.e. post messages to it from multiple threads and poll the queue for messages from a single thread, the consumer thread gets locked. nothing moves forward.

but when i don't use the fixed size property, i.e. don't specify the template parameter `fixed_sized<true>` , the queue works fine. But in this case the queue actually does a memory allocation/deallocation which defeats the purpose of using a lockless queue.

So my question is **"does boost::lockfree::queue becomes a single-producer-single-consumer queue if set with the property `fixed_sized<true>`?"**

is there some different push/pop methods i need to use?

I want an MPMC queue which does not do memory allocation deallocation. if boost does not provide this, is there any other queue that i can use??

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) says "The queue class provides a multi-writer/multi-reader queue", nothing in the documentation indicates this would change with a `fixed_size` policy. Additionally, the boost lock-free queue "uses a freelist for memory management, freed nodes are pushed to the freelist and not returned to the OS before the queue is destroyed" (per default) therefore memory allocation does not occur for every `push` operation even w/o `fixed_size`. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: the question above describes my observations. as soon as i use the `fixed_size` policy, the queue gets stuck if multiple threads call `push()`. It doesnt get stuck if i ensure that only a single thread calls `push()`. How to explain this?

Comment: `push` is documented to be "thread-safe", it would really be nice if you could post a small code example that replicates the problem. Maybe it's even a bug in the boost version you're using. As far as I can see the documentation says it's mutli-write/multi-reader, independent from the policies.

Comment: i will not be able to share the code that i am using. but when i take the example code from boost, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html and modify it with `fixed_size<true>`, the problem doesnt occur. but it does occur in my code. it goes away as soon as i remove the `fixed_size` parameter. i dont know how to explain this.

Comment: If I interpret the docs correctly, the `fixed_size<true>` policy implies two changes: if you call `push` and no further capacity is available, `push` fails and returns `false`. Additionally, the maximum capacity that can be set is limited typically to `2**16-2` elements. You'll have to manually set the capacity via the ctor `queue(size_type)` or the `reserve` member function, the default ctor will set the capacity to `0`. For a capacity of `0`, every `push` will fail.

Comment: yes, i set the size to be 65534 in the queue constructor. and i do push in a loop until it succeeds.

Comment: Ohhh!!!, and as always the bug lies in the user's code. The queue is being polled by a single thread only, whereas there can be multiple producer threads. If, the consumer threads also becomes a producer then there is possibility of a deadlock. as the thread which is supposed to empty the queue, is busy in putting a message in the same queue, as the queue is full, the thread is blocked. and being fixed sized queue there is no possibilty to come out of this situation, whereas in the 'non-fixed' sized queue, the insertion could succeed by allocating another node. Thanks a lot!!! Mr. @DyP

Comment: i want to accept your answer. could you post an answer please. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my question is **does boost::lockfree::queue becomes a single-producer-single-consumer queue if set with the property fixed_size?**

Answer: According to the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html), no. The member functions have different thread safety, but you can use the lockfree queue as a MRMW queue no matter if the policy is `fixed_size<true>` or `fixed_size<false>` (e.g. member functions `push` and `pop` are thread-safe).

See the comments to the OP for a discussion. Short version:

If I interpret the docs correctly, the `fixed_size<true>` policy implies the following changes:

- If you call `push` and no further capacity is available, `push` fails and returns `false`.
- The maximum capacity that can be set is limited typically to 2<sup>16</sup>-2 elements.
- As the capacity is not changed automatically, you'll have to manually set the capacity via the ctor `queue(size_type)` or the `reserve` member function. The default ctor will set the capacity to `0`. (This implies that for the default capacity of `0`, every `push` will fail.)

Comment: as pointed out in the comments to the questions, the bug was in the user code.